# How to add an applet to a webpage

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm trying to make an applet for a website, but I can't put the applet on the website.

This is my html code

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
<applet code="TestCreator.class" width="400" height="400">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

My applet code

```
package me.zachary.self;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class TestCreator extends JApplet {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("test", 100, 100);
    }

}
```

The TestCreator.class is in the same directory as the html file, but whenever I open the html file all that appears is "Test" ("Test" with an uppercase T, not "test" from the applet).

What am I doing wrong and / or how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You're not taking the package into account. Myself, I'd jar that class. Actually I wouldn't use applets.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what would you use instead?

Comment: Something like HTML5/CSS3/JS.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read [why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

I think

```
<applet code="TestCreator.class"
```

shouldn't end in `.class`. Also it should include the package. Like,

```
<applet code="me.zachary.self.TestCreator"
```

And you might find it easier to test your applet with the [appletviewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html).

Comment: and it should be placed in the \me\zachary\self\TestCreator.class path off of the HTML code. A jar file though would rid one of the path requirement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is certainly also true. I should probably have noted that the fully qualified class name *includes* the package.